# How to force the player to keyup?

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

In my program I have a square that jumps over cars. But the player can just hold down space and never touch the ground. This means this can't. I am wondering how o make it force the cube to go back down to the ground after a set time.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Traffic Jumper')

orange = (255, 100, 0)
black = (0,0,0)
grey = (128,128,128)
yellow = (255,255,0)
green = (0,128,0)
red=(255,0,0)
blue = (64,224,208)
brown = (139,69,19)
magenta = (255,0,255)
olive = (128,128,0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def options():
    op = True
    while op:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.QUIT()
            screen.fill(magenta)
            largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
            Textsurf, TextRect = text_objects("Get Hit Bro!", largeText)
            TextRect.center = ((400),(300))
            screen.blit(Textsurf, TextRect)
            smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30)
            Textsurf, TextRect1 = text_objects("Press Y to restart and N to\  leave", smallText)
            TextRect1.center = (400,(400))
            screen.blit(Textsurf, TextRect1)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_y:
                    game_loop()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_n:
                    pygame.quit()

def pause():
    paused = True
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                paused=False
                pygame.QUIT()
                quit()
        screen.fill(olive)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        Textsurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((400),(300))
        screen.blit(Textsurf, TextRect)
        smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',30)
        Textsurf, TextRect1 = text_objects("Press r To Resume", smallText)
        TextRect1.center = (400,(400))
        screen.blit(Textsurf, TextRect1)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    paused = False



def text_objects(text, font):
    textsurface = font.render(text,True,red)
    return textsurface, textsurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    Textsurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((400),(300))
    screen.blit(Textsurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    #game_loop()

def game_loop():
    paused = False
    score = 0
    x = 20
    y = 520
    carx = 1000
    cary = 490
    carspeed = 7
    done = False
    while not done:
            screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
            sky=pygame.draw.rect(screen,blue,pygame.Rect(0,0,800,400))
            grass=pygame.draw.rect(screen,green,pygame.Rect(0,400,800,100))
            floor1=pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,pygame.Rect(0,500,800,10))
            floor2=pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,pygame.Rect(0,590,800,10))
            road=pygame.draw.rect(screen,grey,pygame.Rect(0,510,800,80))
            paint1=pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,pygame.Rect(10,540,100,\ 20))
            paint2=pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,pygame.Rect(200,540,100,\ 20))
            paint3=pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,pygame.Rect(400,540,100,\ 20))
            paint4=pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,pygame.Rect(600,540,100,\ 20))
            paint5=pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,pygame.Rect(780,540,100,\ 20))
            player=pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, pygame.Rect(x, y, 60,\ 60))
            car=pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,pygame.Rect(carx,cary,80,\ 95))
            if x > 800 - 60:
                x -= 3
            elif x < 0:
                x += 3
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    #done = True
                    quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                y -= 200   
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                y += 200
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p:
                pause()


            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            #if pressed[pygame.K_UP]: y -= 3
            #if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]: y += 3
            if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: x -= 3
            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: x += 3
            carx -= carspeed
            if carx < -100:
                score += 1
                carspeed += 0.2
                carx = 1000

            if x > carx - 55 and x < carx + 55 and y > cary:
                #message_display('Get Hit Bro!')
                options()
                font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
                text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(score) ,True,black)
                screen.blit(text,(0,0))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
game_loop()
```

Comment: What library are you using? What is `event`?

Comment: I just put all my code in

Answer (score 2):

Add these variables to game_loop:

```
    hasJumped = False
    jumpCooldown = 0.0
```

In your loop, in the 'while not done' add

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if hasJumped == False:
                y -= 200
                hasJumped = True
    if hasJumped == True:        
        jumpCooldown += clock.get_time()
    if jumpCooldown > [Jump Cooldown Limit]: # Set this number to the amount of time the car can jump at once. You'll have to experiment.
        hasJumped = False
        jumpCooldown = 0.0
```

PS : I don't understand why you use pygame.KEYDOWN/KEYUP to detect one set of keys and pygame.key.get_pressed() for another set. It seems messy

Answer (score 0):

You could have a counter that was set each time the player presses space. This counter could count down each iteration, and when it reaches zero, the y position would be set back:

```
delta_y = 0
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    counter = 10   
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    counter = 0
if counter > 0:
    delta_y = 200
    counter -= 1
else:
    delta_y = 0
```

You have to set `counter = 0` outside the while loop. I've added a `delta_y` to the vertical position, because this is a little more cleaner way to do it. You have to update this line to:

```
player=pygame.draw.rect(screen, orange, pygame.Rect(x, y + delta_y, 60, 60))
```

The counter counts down from 10 - you'll just have to experiment with that.